# Turn List of Dictionaries into Dictionary of Dictionaries with index

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries, like this:

```
ls_dict = [{'py': 'Python', 'mat': 'MATLAB', 'cs': 'Csharp'}, 
{'A': 65, 'B': 66, 'C': 67}, 
{'a': 97, 'b': 98, 'c': 99}]
```

Which produces this:

```
[{'py': 'Python', 'mat': 'MATLAB', 'cs': 'Csharp'}, {'A': 65, 'B': 66, 'C': 67}, {'a': 97, 'b': 98, 'c': 99}]
```

What I want is a dictionary of dictionaries where each dictionary is indexed like the following:

```
{"0": {'py': 'Python', 'mat': 'MATLAB', 'cs': 'Csharp'}, "1": {'A': 65, 'B': 66, 'C': 67}, 2: {'a': 97, 'b': 98, 'c': 99}}
```

The additional problem is that I need to convert the former to the latter, rather than adapting my sample creation code, as I just spent 15 hours downloading the data into the current (wrong) format.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: `dict(enumerate(ls_dict))`

Comment: Why anyone would you ever want to use a dict with sequential numbers as key is a bit of a mystery. ..

Comment: It is an old input that I inherited that I am recreating. I need it in that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate), so:

```
In [75]: {str(index): lst for index, lst in enumerate(ls_dict)}
Out[75]: 
{'0': {'py': 'Python', 'mat': 'MATLAB', 'cs': 'Csharp'},
 '1': {'A': 65, 'B': 66, 'C': 67},
 '2': {'a': 97, 'b': 98, 'c': 99}}
```

Answer (score 0):

hello you need to do this whit for

```
keyList = ['0','1','2']
valueList = [{'py': 'Python', 'mat': 'MATLAB', 'cs': 'Csharp'}, {'A': 65, 'B': 66, 'C': 67}, {'a': 97, 'b': 98, 'c': 99}]
d = {}
for i in range(len(keyList)):
    d[keyList[i]] = valueList[i]
print(d)
```

Comment: Thank you Ali. That does work, although in my case, the keylist is several million entries, so would need to adapt it slightly :)

Comment: you can also use enumerate on your list of dictionaries... that way you get your indexes in one shot.